# Create a clients we work with automatic slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I want to create a "Clients that work with us" section on my website but I am not sure how to go about doing so. I want it to slide across consistenly rotating between the companies. A good example of one I'd like to replicate is on pickspace.com. I believe they got it from WordPress. Any suggestions on how to replicate this or a thread saying how to do it? Thanks for the help in advance!

```js
 /*=============== Partners Section ===============*/

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.partners-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoints: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoints: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});



 
/*=============== SHOW MENU ===============*/
const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu'),
      navToggle = document.getElementById('nav-toggle'),
      navClose = document.getElementById('nav-close')

/*===== MENU SHOW =====*/
/* Validate if constant exists */
if(navToggle){
    navToggle.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        navMenu.classList.add('show-menu')
    })
}

/*===== MENU HIDDEN =====*/
/* Validate if constant exists */
if(navClose){
    navClose.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        navMenu.classList.remove('show-menu')
    })
}


/*=============== SERVICES MODAL ===============*/
const modalViews = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal'),
      modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.services__button'),
      modalClose = document.querySelectorAll('.services__modal-close')

let modal = function(modalClick){
    modalViews[modalClick].classList.add('active-modal')
}

modalBtns.forEach((mb, i) =>{
    mb.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        modal(i)
    })
})

modalClose.forEach((mc) =>{
    mc.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        modalViews.forEach((mv) =>{
            mv.classList.remove('active-modal')
        })
    })
})



/*=============== REMOVE MENU MOBILE ===============*/
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

function linkAction(){
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
    // When we click on each nav__link, we remove the show-menu class
    navMenu.classList.remove('show-menu')
}
navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener('click', linkAction))

/*=============== GSAP ANIMATION ===============*/
TweenMax.from('.home__title', 1, {delay: .2, opacity: 0, y: 20,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__description', 1, {delay: .3, opacity: 0, y: 20,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__button', 1, {delay: .4, opacity: 0, y: 20,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__liquid', 1, {delay: .7, opacity: 0, y: 200,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__juice-animate', 1, {delay: 1.2, opacity: 0, y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__apple1', 1, {delay: 1.5,opacity: 0,y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__apple2', 1, {delay: 1.6,opacity: 0,y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__leaf:nth-child(1)', 2, {delay: 1.3,opacity: 0,y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__leaf:nth-child(2)', 2, {delay: 1.4,opacity: 0,y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__leaf:nth-child(3)', 2, {delay: 1.5,opacity: 0,y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__leaf:nth-child(4)', 2, {delay: 1.6,opacity: 0,y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__leaf:nth-child(5)', 2, {delay: 1.7,opacity: 0,y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
TweenMax.from('.home__leaf:nth-child(6)', 2, {delay: 1.8,opacity: 0,y: -800,ease: Expo.easeInOut})
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}
.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;

}

.slick-list {
position: relative;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}

[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide {
float: right;
}

.slick-slide img{
  display: block;
}

.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide.slick-list.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       
        <!--=============== FAVICON ===============-->

        <!--=============== REMIXICONS ===============-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--=============== BOXICONS ===============-->
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        
        <!--=============== CSS ===============-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/scroll_nav.css">

       
        

        <meta name="theme-color" content="hsl(196, 60%, 91%)">
        
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="yes">



    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="pageloader"></div>


        <!--==================== HEADER ====================-->
        

        <!--==================== MAIN ====================-->
        <main class="main">

            <!--==================== HOME ====================-->
           
<!--=============== End of Home ===============-->



<!--==================== ABOUT ====================-->





<!--=============== Partners ===============-->

<div class="container">
    <h2 class="section__title">Clients We Work With</h2>
        <section class="partners-logos slider">
                        

            <div class="slide"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Original_Adidas_logo.svg/779px-Original_Adidas_logo.svg.png" alt=""></div> 
            <div class="slide"><img src="/assets/img/pinkflower-removebg-preview.png" alt=""></div> 
            <div class="slide"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Original_Adidas_logo.svg/779px-Original_Adidas_logo.svg.png" alt=""></div>
            
            <div class="slide"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Original_Adidas_logo.svg/779px-Original_Adidas_logo.svg.png" alt=""></div> 
            
            <div class="slide"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Original_Adidas_logo.svg/779px-Original_Adidas_logo.svg.png" alt=""></div>
            
            <div class="slide"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Original_Adidas_logo.svg/779px-Original_Adidas_logo.svg.png" alt=""></div>
            
            <div class="slide"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Original_Adidas_logo.svg/779px-Original_Adidas_logo.svg.png" alt=""></div>
            
                
            
        </section>

</div>



<!--=============== SERVICES ===============-->

<!--=============== End of SERVICES ===============-->

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


        </main>
        

        <script>
            var loader = document.getElementById("pageloader");
          
            window.addEventListener("load", function(){
              loader.style.display = "none";
            })
          </script>


     

        <!--=============== GSAP ===============-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>        

        
        <!--=============== MAIN JS ===============-->
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/scroll_nav.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: In WordPress I create a custom post type to provide the icon image and its html, then grab a slider plugin like slick.js to provide the slider function.

Comment: @David Hey I appreciate the response. After some research, I found slick carousel. Ive been working on it and coding it. For some reason my code works properly when inputted on fiddle but not on my website or on stackoverflows code snippet. Ive been reviewing the code for a good amount of time trying to see what the issue can be. Any suggestions? I have added my code into the snippet above and here is a link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ao0ug3vh/9/

Answer (score 1):

A marquee is a original html tag for scrolling and this site has a working example on how to do a scrolling box using marquee and css.

https://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/html-scrolling-text.cfm

Comment: I tried to use that however I was having some issues inputting photos instead of text. I believe that I found the solution to my question however I am having some strange issues. My code works properly when inputted on fiddle but not on my website or on stackoverflow code snippet. Ive been reviewing the code for a good amount of time trying to see what the issue can be. Any suggestions? I have added my code into the snippet above and here is a link to my fiddle jsfiddle.net/ao0ug3vh/9

Comment: HI, okay I took a quick look. What I found is that  when I remove the slide              <div class="slide"><img src="/assets/img/pinkflower-removebg-preview.png" alt=""></div>     and use the addidas logo then it works fine. I would suggest that you look at or check the following: 1. That the slide pinkflower exists. 2. that the slide is the same size ( height and width) as the addidas logo.  3. that maybe if the above to dont work then possible the picture resolution is different - but I doubt that would matter.